# Convert AS3 into Cocos2D

Tags: actionscript-3, cocos2d-iphone

So i have a "old" game i made, i wanna try make it for iPhone(ofc).

Can some one please help me try rewrite this into cocos2d ? im using xcode 4, think thers a bit different about the releases, of what i have heard, but dunno..

But thanks in advance

heres my AS3 code:

```
for (i = 0; i < 11; i++)
{
    columns = [];
    for (j = 0; j < 11; j++)
    {
        _place = new place();
        _place.thisX=i;
        _place.thisY=j;
        _place.thisDistance=Math.min(i+1,j+1,11-i,11-j)*11;
        _place.y = 56 * i + 3;
        _place.x = 5 + 71 * j + 35*(i%2);
        _place.buttonMode=true;
        _place.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, setBlock);
        columns[j] = _place;

        addChild(_place);
    }
    rows[i] = columns;
}
```

i've got this so far, but its prob. wrong

```
place = [CCSprite spriteWithFile:@"place.gif"];

        int *i;
        int *j;
        CCSprite *_place = place;
        CCArray *columns;

        for (i = 0; i < 11; i++) {
            columns = [];
            for (j = 0; j < 11; j++) {
                _place.position.x = ccp(i);
                _place.position.y = ccp(j);
            }
        }
```

Comment: I'm confused what you're asking for here. Do you simply want someone to write the code for you? Because that's not a question. Now if there is something specific wrong with the code you've written (eg. it gives an error message when you compile, or you don't know how to implement the touch functionality, or whatever) then ask about that problem.

Comment: na na, just wanted some help to, how to rewrite the AS3 into cocos :)

Comment: riiiight, in your original post you already made a vague request for help. But what exactly do you need help with? Which parts of the code are you having difficulty with? What difficulties? Be specific, don't just throw out a bunch of random code and say "help!"

Comment: well.. i need help with all the code, thats why i posted it.. how do i rewrite a instance like in AS3 place = new place, with arrays, distince, position ect.. i get a lot of errors, thats why i posted it, hoping that some one could help, tell me what was wrong ect ect..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

are you sure your code is written in c++, objective-c or just native c? this is how you have to implement your code :

```
CCSprite *places[11][11];
for(int i=0;i<11;i++)
    for(int j=0;j<11;j++)
    {
        places[i][j] = [CCSprite spriteWithFile:@"place.gif"];
        places[i][j]->position = ccp(i*11,j*11);
    }
```

and you can also add `[layer addChild:places[i][j]]` at the end of for loop to add them to your layer at creation time.

--edit--

and for creating a UI just as I can get from your AC3 script I would prefer using CCMenu class:

something like this :

```
CCMenuItemImage *places[11][11];
CCMenu* menu = [CCMenu menuWithItems:nil];
for(int i=0;i<11;i++)
    for(int j=0;j<11;j++)
    {
        places[i][j] = [CCMenuItemImage itemFromNormalImage:@"place.gif" selecetedImage:@"place.gif" target:self selector:@selector(clickEvent)];
        places[i][j]->position = ccp(i*11,j*11);
        [menu addchild:places[i][j];
    }
```

Comment: its written in AS3, in flash cs5.. but the code in the bottom is "should" be cocos2d :p but thanks ill give it a try

Comment: @patrick R: i wan't talking about your AS3 code, I was saying your second code should create around 10 or 15 compile errors! and can't be compiled in xcode!

Comment: ya it did gave a lot of errors :/ but just tried the solution you gave me and i got only this error: CCSprite' does not have a member named 'position'; at this line: places[i][j]->position = ccp(i*11,j*11);